# Filter many to many field in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm having trouble trying to get a query set.

I have:

```
class RangeDate(models.Model):
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(_("Start Date"))
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(_("End Date"))


class Product(models.Model):
    start_end_dates = models.ManyToManyField(RangeDate)
```

So im trying to get all the products. And only show the RangeDates that the start date is greater than datetime.now(). I don't know if a queryset can give that result or if i need to treat them in a cycle.

Also i need to order the dates in the products

Hope you can help me. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 1**
So i make this, but i think that it might be a better way:

```
product = Product.objects.filter(start_end_dates__start_date__gt=
                                   datetime.now())
```

but if the product has one greater and one lower than now it also gives me the product and it gives me repeated products so i use:

```
product = Product.objects.filter(start_end_dates__start_date__gt=
                                   datetime.now()).distinct()
```

then in the model i made a function for checking the dates:

```
def is_older_than_now(self):
    return self.start_date < datetime.now()
```

and i call it in the template:

```
 {% if not date.is_older_than_now %}
     ---
 {%endif}
```

and a filter tag for ordering:

```
{% for date in product.start_end_dates.all|order_by:"start_date" %}
    ---
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for the `__gt` modifier. `ManyToManyField`s can be queried and filtered like regular fields, and filtering on a field in the related model just requires a dunderscore (`__`).

This query should work to get all Products with a start date after today:

```
import datetime
Product.objects.filter(start_end_dates__start_date__gt=datetime.now())
```

---

Based on the edit if you need a list of Products that have start dates that are *all* after 'now', then thats just a matter of some boolean fiddling:

A "product that has all ranges with a start greater than now" is equivalent to "a product that has does not have any ranges less than now". Which can be done with [a `Q` object](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects):

```
from django.db.models import Q
Product.objects.filter(~Q(start_end_dates__start_date__lte=datetime.now()))
```

The section `~Q(...)` is in effect saying "not this query (the `~`)", so its saying:

> Filter Products by those that have *not* got a `start_end_dates` with a `start_date` less than today.

Comment: That doesn't work very well. Because, if the product has relation with one greater than and one lower than RangeDate it also gives the Product.

Comment: That wasn't part of the question when I initially answered it, I'll see if I can improve based on the update.

Comment: @Lego Stormtroopr, `Q()` is qool, but you could also use `.objects.exclude()` instead of `.objects.filter()`